# "This edit would have to be a suggested edit." error is confusing and unclear

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

I tried to suggest an edit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18565352/254830) to retag it. I clicked the edit button, added my tags, and hit submit to get... this strange error.

[image: Screenshot of the edit page with an error saying: "This edit would have to be a suggested edit."]

This didn't make much sense to me. *"I know it would have to be,"* I thought. *"That's why I'm here, right? All my edits are only suggested edits at this point."* I hit *Save Edits* again to receive the same error. I had no idea what was going on, why I was getting an error, and what it was trying to tell me.

It was only once I went back to the question that I found out what was going on: someone else had suggested an edit on this question. I suppose that's what the error was about.

[image]

This error doesn't make much sense. Can its wording be changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was another edit suggested on the same post you were trying to edit (kept for peer review). That is why you were getting that error.

Yes the message seems to be unclear, maybe someone needs to modify that?