# Provide link to current 'Suggested Edit' in error message following a 'Suggested Edit' conflict

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, suggested-edits

Currently when two users attempt to suggest an edit, the user that submits theirs last may receive this error:

[image: "This edit would have to be a suggested edit."]

As [has been brought up before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190687/198272), this error message isn't very user-friendly. It also isn't very functional.  What if I want to see what edits the other user is suggesting?  I am not a 2K+ user so I'm not sure if higher-rep users encounter this, but if they did wouldn't it be nice to have a quick way to review the suggested edit?  If we took the time to suggest an edit, leaving us with an empty bag and no ability to follow-up on the post isn't a great user experience.

How about something like this instead:

[image: "A suggested edit has already been made by StackExchangeUser."]

Maybe with different flavor text depending on the viewer's ability to review a suggested edit (a <2K user may just want to view the suggestion, while a >=2K user may want to participate in the review), but hopefully this is enough to start a discussion on improving this functionality.

Comment: The "edit" link on the post links to the relevant review queue item for 2k+ users if there is a pending suggested edit.

Comment: @Servy Good to know. It is greyed out for us that aren't, which is unfortunate because sometimes I would like to see other suggestions even if I can't assist with the review yet.

Comment: @HyperAnthony Somebody asked the same question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195460/this-edit-would-have-to-be-a-suggested-edit-error-is-confusing-and-unclear?lq=1), and it was marked as a duplicate as the one I linked before.

Answer (score 1):

This error message should never appear to users with full editing rights - their edit would just quietly reject the pending suggested edit upon submission.

Since the only folks who should ever see this by definition *can't approve others' suggested edits*, providing them with a link to the edit is rather pointless.

We have, however, [tried to clarify the error message a bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190687/this-edit-would-have-to-be-a-suggested-edit-edit-button-grayed-out/191915#191915).